# Why does PCA require/benefit from homoscedasticity?

Tags: pca, heteroscedasticity

Why does PCA specifically (and dimensionality reduction methods in general) require that the variance remains constant across the different values of the mean?

An explanation not relying on strong statistical knowledge would be best, if possible.

Comment: Clustering is usually applied to multiple variables, are you is each of them needs to have same variance and be homoscedastic? PCA is not clustering algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking why the variables needs  to have the same variance across the mean (be homoscedastic).

Comment: It doesn’t for clustering, but are you asking about clustering or PCA?

Comment: PCA. Sorry, have fixed the question.

Comment: Homoscedasticity does not even seem an ideal for PCA. If variables have very different units of measurement, then standardizing variables before PCA, or equivalently working with the correlation matrix, is essential. That's not a fix for heteroscedasticity; it is a fix for varying units. If variables have the same units, their different variances are usually of interest and importance for PCA, but if they are irrelevant for a given goal, then standardization is called for, as a matter of purpose.

Comment: No reference is source is given for this puzzling claim.